# Как задавать свойства при создании Mock объекта?

Tags: php, yii2, юнит-тесты, phpunit, codeception

Имеется класс наследующийся от ActiveRecord. Задача стоит мОкнуть ActiveRecord класс, и задать ему нужные аттрибуты. Вопрос: можно ли задавать аттрибуты при создании Mock-объекта в phpUnit? Сейчас я реализую это так:

```
protected function createMockDepartment(array $attributes)
{
    $department = $this->getMockBuilder(EmployeeDepartment::class)
        ->setMethods(['save', 'attributes'])
        ->getMock();
    $department->method('save')->willReturn(true);
    $department->method('attributes')->willReturn([
        'ID_DEPARTMENT',
        'DEPARTMENT_NAME',
        'IS_ACTIVE',
        'DEPARTMENT_REGION',
    ]);

    foreach ($attributes as $key => $attribute) {
        $department->$key = $attribute;
    }

    return $department;
}
```

Можно ли обойтись без цикла?